# PHP pregmatch to pull values after a info

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a bunch of logging in a text file and im trying to use pregmatch to pull the info directly after the colon, for example i have:

> 04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Architecture: 64 bits
>   04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1

I have this code which works on similar ones ive used before but im a regex newbie and it doesnt seem to work here:

```
preg_match('/Operating System Architecture: (.+?)<br>/', $body, $os_bit);
preg_match('/Operating System Service Pack: (.+?)<br>/', $body, $os_service_pack);
```

but when i echo this

```
echo $os_bit[1];
echo $os_service_pack[1];
```

I get nothing returned

The body is a huge log file so i just pulled the snippet of relevant info above so hopefully thats enough. Theres about 8 of these all on new lines like the examples above so if i get one ill be able to get all

Comment: I think you need to escape `<` and `>` like this `\<br\>` also try adding `is` after the last `/` it will add multiline search and case insensitivity.

Comment: Surely if you're reading this from a text file, the lines are broken by newline characters? (`\r?\n`) `<br>` is a HTML element, not a generic line break

Comment: @Ryan: there are 11 characters with special meanings: the opening square bracket [, the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening round bracket ( and the closing round bracket ).

Comment: You also might want to use the `preg_match_all` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `preg_match` a log file? In that case, end-of-lines should not be `<br>` but just a newline (`\n`). Since dots usually don't match newlines unless you use `/s` at the end, try:

```
preg_match('/Operating System Architecture: (.*)/', $body, $os_bit);
preg_match('/Operating System Service Pack: (.*)/', $body, $os_service_pack);
```

Also, note that `$os_bit` and `$os_service_pack` would be arrays, so to debug you probably want to use `print_r($os_bit);`

Comment: This one seemed to do the trick, realize with the info provided it probably wasnt an easy task to guess so thanks for everyone that tried

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was able to come up with based on the amount of data provided:

```
<?php
$body = "
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Architecture: 64 bits 
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Architecture: 64 bits 
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Architecture: 64 bits 
04:28:17.409 [Main:1 - Bootstrapper.LogSystemInfo] Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1";

preg_match_all('/(Operating System Architecture:.*)(\n|$)/i', $body, $os_bit);
preg_match_all('/(Operating System Service Pack:.*)(\n|$)/i', $body, $os_service_pack);

print_r($os_bit[1]);
print_r($os_service_pack[1]);
```

Which then results in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Operating System Architecture: 64 bits
    [1] => Operating System Architecture: 64 bits
    [2] => Operating System Architecture: 64 bits
)
Array
(
    [0] => Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1
    [1] => Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1
    [2] => Operating System Service Pack: Service Pack 1
)
```